# Invertibility in the Complex Group Ring

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, group-rings

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete group, and let $\Bbb{C}[\Gamma]$ be the associated complex group ring. If $\sum_{g \in \Gamma} a_g g$ represents some element in the group ring, where all but finitely many of the $a_g \in \Bbb{C}$ are nonzero, then we can equip $\Bbb{C}[\Gamma]$ with the follow natural involution:

$$\left(\sum_{g \in \Gamma} a_g g \right)^* := \sum_{g \in \Gamma} \overline{a_g} g^{-1}$$

This gives us a notion of self-adjoint elemnts ($f^* = f$ for $f \in \Bbb{C}[\Gamma]$) and positive elements (those of the form $\sum h_i^* h_i$ for $h_i \in \Bbb{C}[\Gamma]$). From here we can get an ordering on the self-adjoint elements: $f \le g$ if and only if $g - f$ is positive.

I am wondering whether the following is true:

> Let $f \in \Bbb{C}[\Gamma]$ be a positive element. Then $f$ is invertible in $\Bbb{C}[\Gamma]$ if and only if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f \ge \epsilon 1$.

I know this is true for $C^*$-algebras, and I suspect that the proof just amounts to $C^*$-algebraic tricks. For example, the forward direction is trivial, because if $f$ is invertible in $\Bbb{C}[\Gamma]$, then it is invertible in the full group $C^*$-algebra $C^*(\Gamma)$, which is just the completion of $\Bbb{C}[\Gamma]$ with respect to a particular norm (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741889/full-or-universal-group-c-algebra-of-discrete-group-gamma)). However, the other direction is not obvious. If $f \ge \epsilon 1$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, then $f$ is invertible in $C^*(\Gamma)$. But why must its inverse live in $\Bbb{C}[\Gamma]$?

My gut tells me this is true, but I don't see it at the moment.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but is your positivity strict in the sense that if $h\in\mathbb{C}[\Gamma]$ is positive, then $-h$ is not? I don't see where that necessarily follows from the definitions, though I can't immediately counter-example it either...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Hmm...That's a good question. I don't think so, because $0 = 0*0$, so $0$ is positive because it is a sum of hermitian squares; but $-0 = 0$ is also positive. So I guess the positivity is not strict.

Comment: EDIT: $0 = 0^* \cdot 0$

Comment: Sorry — I should've been more specific there myself; you of course had the mixed inequality. I more meant whether it's possible for $h$ and $-h$ to both be positive when neither one is $0$. That said, I think I just convinced myself of that — if $h=gg^*$ then the 'constant' term of $h$ (that is, the term multiplied by the unit of the group) must be (strictly) positive, so that rules out the consideration I had.

Comment: Did you try with $\Gamma=\Bbb{Z}=\langle g\rangle$ ? $\frac14 g^{-2}+g^0+\frac14 g^2$ is positive but its inverse is an infinite series $\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{4^k} (g^{-2}+g^2)^k$

Comment: @MartinArgerami It is the OP who said sum of two positive elements is positive, which is what we'd obtain if it worked as in $M_n(\Bbb{R})$ (where we have the criterion $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}^n, x^\top A x\ge 0$)

Comment: @MartinArgerami The OP didn't define positive as $A^*A$ but as $\sum_{j=1}^J A_j^* A_j$. Why not make clear the different notions of positivity we have and how it does/doesn't work as in $M_n(\Bbb{C})$ when taking/not taking the completion for one or other norm/topology ?

Comment: I missed that. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Very little C$^*$-algebra theory applies to $*$-algebras. The main problem is the following: consider for instance the element $1\in \mathbb C[\mathbb Z]$, the identity. What's its spectrum? To avoid confusing the elements of $\mathbb Z$ with scalars, consider instead $G=\{V^n:\ n\in\mathbb Z\}$, where $V$ is a unitary with infinite spectrum (so that $G\simeq \mathbb Z$); we need to ask ourselves when is $V-\lambda I$ invertible. This requires us to write
$$
(V-\lambda I)^{-1}=\sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_j\,V^{k_j}
$$
for some $k_1,\ldots,k_m\in\mathbb Z$; by "filling the gaps with $0$" we may write $\sum_{j=-r}^{r}\alpha_jV^j$. So we need to have
\begin{align}
I&=(V-\lambda)(V-\lambda)^{-1}=\sum_{j=-r}^r \alpha_j\,V^{j+1}-\sum_{j=-r}^r \lambda\alpha_j\,V^{j}\\[0.3cm] &=-\lambda\alpha_{-r}V^{-r}+\alpha_rV^{r+1}+\sum_{-r+1}^r(\alpha_{j-1}-\lambda\alpha_j)V^j.
\end{align}
Linear independence then forces us to have $$\alpha_{-1}-\lambda\alpha_0=1, \ \ \ \lambda\alpha_{-r}=0,\ \ \ \alpha_r=0,\ \  \ \alpha_{j-1}-\lambda\alpha_j=0.$$
When $\lambda=0$ this works, since $V$ is invertible. If $\lambda\ne0$, the equations are impossible: we start from $\alpha_r=0$; then $\alpha_{r-1}=\lambda\alpha_r=0$ and so $\alpha_{j}=0$ for $j=0,\ldots,r$. Further, $\alpha_{-1}=1+\lambda\alpha_0=1$, and then $\alpha_{-2}=\ldots=\alpha_{-r}=1$, and we get a contradiction. So
$$
\sigma(V)=\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}. 
$$

In this context you can apply reuns example: take $f=(V+V^{-1})^*(V+V^{-1})=(V+V^{-1})^2=V^2+2I+V^{-2}$. Then $f+I\geq 1$. Suppose that $f+I$ is invertible: then its inverse should be of the form $\sum_{j=-r}^r \alpha_j V^j$. We should have
\begin{align}
I&=(V^2+3I+V^{-2})\sum_{j=-r}^r \alpha_j V^j.
\end{align}
By linear independence and looking at the terms with higest and lowest degree we get $\alpha_{r}=\alpha_{-r}=0$. Repeating the argument we get $\alpha_j=0$ for all $j$, a contradiction that shows that $f+I$ is not invertible.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble connecting what you said to the question of whether $f \ge \epsilon 1$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ implies that $f$ is invertible.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that there is little to no reason to think that a $*$-algebra will behave like a C$^*$-algebra, and I gave you a concrete example of that with the spectrum. At the end I have included the natural counterexample, that was mentioned by reuns in the comments.